# How do I upgrade a database using WIX?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, wix3.5, database-project

I have a Visual Studio 2010 database project and a WIX installer. What is the best way to go about installing that database to a server using that WIX installer? How would I set that up?

I'm having a hard time with WIX as it is, so hopefully somebody has some insight into how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so difficult at all. First you need to have the DB script file and then use the WiX SqlExtension. The next tutorial will help on your purpose.

[WiX tutorial: Lesson 7 SQL](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/sql)